# Difference between geometry and geography in ST_Azimuth function of PostGIS

Tags: geometry, postgis, geography, azimuth

I would like to ask what is the difference between geometry and geography using the PostGIS function `ST_Azimuth`.

When I execute the following query:

```
SELECT degrees( ST_Azimuth(ST_MakePoint(21.304116745663165, 38.68607570952619), ST_MakePoint(21.286237118117278,38.71455640443629)) )
```

I get `327.880195438529` degrees.

But when I cast the geometries to geography as the following query :

```
SELECT degrees( ST_Azimuth(ST_MakePoint(21.304116745663165, 38.68607570952619)::geography, ST_MakePoint(21.286237118117278,38.71455640443629)::geography) )
```

I get `333.810802282843` degrees.

Does the cast to geography give a more accurate result? Or a different calculation is made?

My geometries have SRID=4326.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me as if geography gives you the point-point azimuth on the WGS84 Earth (so an approximately spherical surface) while the geometry gives you the point-point azimuth on the plane.

So, yes, a different calculation is made.

Comment: So when i have lon/lat point should i use geography in order to take into consideration the Earths surface?

Comment: Yes, unless you are building tunnels through the Earth in which case use a 3D geometry :-)